# Test doubles for VSCode API objects

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, vscode-extensions

I have a constructor like this:

```
constructor(private editor: vscode.TextEditor) { /* ... */ }
```

I use the `editor.selections` property.

In a unit test (using mocha), I don't have access to a live `vscode.TextEditor`, so how do I pass a test double into that?

Comment: Create a Test Double to match the type of `vscode.TextEditor`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 What's the easiest way to do that?